# How are helium files stored on Google My Drive?

Tags: backup, helium

It usually takes me several tries to get all my Android files to Google Drive using Helium.  But finally it always seems to work. (155 files yesterday)

When I then look at One Drive I don't see a Helium Backup folder as I would expect.  Instead there are multiple files listed on the right under the Activity tab.  With other backup programs the files are easily visible in a backup folder.

Is there any way to verify the backup is okay?  It seems to me the only way to have peace of mind that your backup is perfect is to restore to another phone and see if everything's there.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated.